# Get rid of openshift welcome page

Tags: nginx, openshift, redmine, openshift-client-tools, openshift-cartridge

I have created an application on openshift with Nginx cartridge. Added, committed, and pushed successfully using git, but when I click to view the application it shows:

> Welcome to your Ngnix application on OpenShift

Which file should I change, so that I can view my application and get rid of this welcome page?

Comment: What files are available in your git repo to change?  Can you provide a link to the Nginx cartridge that you used?

Comment: Heh, thank you, I solved this issue by deleting another app that was colliding with my main app.